# pivot_wider in R to get a distance matrix from three columns

Tags: r, dataframe, pivot

I have a dataframe with 3 columns as the following:

```
set.seed(123)

demo_data <- data.frame(
  
  query = rep(sprintf("ID%s", c(1:4)),4),
  target = rep(sprintf("ID%s", c(1:4)), each = 4),
  dist = round(runif(min = 40, max = 100, n = 16))
  
)
```

I'm planning to get a matrix where the values listed in `query` and `target` columns are the new columns and the ANI values are to each cell in the dataframe, something like this:

|  | ID1 | ID2 | ID3 | ID4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | 55 | 93 | 79 | 57 |
| ID2 | 43 | 82 | 83 | 49 |
| ID3 | 60 | 78 | 73 | 98 |
| ID4 | 97 | 100 | 76 | 94 |

PD: these are synthetic values, in my original data I want the diagonal to be 100 for each cell (the same against the same).

Comment: What's `ANI`? For that seed , `[D1,D1]` should be  57 not 55. Or is that table not filled with values from `demo_data`? Are you perhaps after `pivot_wider(demo_data, names_from = "target", values_from = "dist")` ?

Comment: Is it Average nucleotide identity

Comment: @margusl, the code block that initializes demo_data will give different random number when it run at  second time, which actually he expect, in first run it will produce, [D1,D1] as 57, but in second run it will the entire value will change, and [D1,D1] will produce 55 and  then only above like data structure will be formed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how we can do it with `pivot_wider` and `column_to_rownames`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)

demo_data %>%
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = target, 
    values_from = dist,
    id_cols = query
  ) %>%
  column_to_rownames(var = "query") 

  ID1 ID2 ID3 ID4
ID1  57  96  73  81
ID2  87  43  67  74
ID3  65  72  97  46
ID4  93  94  67  94
```

Answer (score 5):

You can simply run `xtabs`

```
> xtabs(dist ~ ., demo_data)
     target
query ID1 ID2 ID3 ID4
  ID1  57  96  73  81
  ID2  87  43  67  74
  ID3  65  72  97  46
  ID4  93  94  67  94
```

Answer (score 2):

```
set.seed(123)

demo_data <- data.frame(
  
  query = rep(sprintf("ID%s", c(1:4)),4),
  target = rep(sprintf("ID%s", c(1:4)), each = 4),
  dist = round(runif(min = 40, max = 100, n = 16))
  
)

library(tidyr)


# Spread the data into wide format
wide_matrix <- spread(demo_data, target, dist)

print(wide_matrix)

query ID1 ID2 ID3 ID4
1   ID1  55  93  79  57
2   ID2  43  82  83  49
3   ID3  60  78  73  98
4   ID4  97 100  76  94
```